# How to loop the program , something like "goto" in Basic

Tags: python

```
print ("----------------------------------------")
print ("name of the program")
print ("----------------------------------------")

import math

squareroot = int(input("Choose number:"))
answer = math.sqrt(squareroot)
print ("Answer is ",answer)

input("DONE: ")
```

I'm asking how to "loop" it , something like goto in Basic
simply , on the end of the code i would like that program would ask me 
-- "wanna go again ? y/n"

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GotoConsideredHarmful

Comment: @leeor even more relevant: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: @DanielRoseman classic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your logic with `while`:

```
>>> while True:
...     squareroot = int(input("Choose number:"))
...     answer = math.sqrt(squareroot)
...     print ("Answer is ",answer)
...     
...     if input("DONE: ").strip().lower() == 'y':
...         break
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to loop through your logic until you give it something to "break" on. The idea is that you loop and keep asking the user input, if they provide a particular key word to end, then you catch that and use the keyword 'break', to end the loop.

Here is a very simple example that illustrates how to use it. You should be able to figure out how to apply it to your code.

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter something: ")
    if user_input == "done":
        break
    else:
        # do stuff with user_input
```